# How Do I Fix the Carousel Slider Controls?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm trying to setup a CSS carousel, when I wrote the code the automatic sliding seems to work okay, although it seems little buggy. However the main issue is the prev and next controls don't work properly. Every time you click one of them they always start you from the active-item image so you can never fully click through the images.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/parvazlogo.jpg" alt="program" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                  <h1></h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/program1.jpg" alt="programming image" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                  <h1>ParwazTech Will Bring your Ideas To Life!</h1>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/innovation.jpg" alt="innovation" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                  <h1>Learn More about Us</h1>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/office.jpg" alt="deal struck" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">

                  <h1>Start looking at deals now!</h1>
                </div>

              </div>
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">next</span>
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As i see your code, you are using Bootstrap. Then why don't you use Bootstrap carousel itself?

Comment: @SaiManoj I thought I was using the Bootstrap Carousel?

Comment: You have mentioned that  you were using `css carousel` in question. Which version of Bootstrap ?

Comment: @SaiManj Bootstrap v3.4.1

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h
Please go through this

Comment: @SaiManoj I've gone through a number of tutorials and examples like this online, and I just tried the example you provided once again. The results are the same, it slides automatically fine, and the three data-slide buttons at the bottom work, but the two right and left buttons only move from the active item

Comment: Maybe you can upload a gift of your error, because for what I read, clicking on a right/left button, would move the current item, to the one on the left or right of the *active* one, makes sense and sounds like works as intended

Comment: @MatiasFernandezMartinez take a look at the example https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h   when you click right or left it moves from the image it is currently set on, not the one you wrote as class= "item active". The problem in my code is that it only moves from the item with that active class, which prevents sliding through all of them manually

Comment: @WajKhan I tried your code and works fine, what do you mean by the active item? the `active` class is set to the correct item when you press the controls left or right :
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G69ZRBEO2D0R

Comment: @MatiasFernandezMartinez Let me try an explain this in the most clear terms as possible. As you can see in my orginal code above I have three items. No matter which slide the carousel is on, if I click a left arrow key it instantly switches to the picture with the active class(in my case the first picture listed) and then goes to the left from there. Same thing vice versa for the right, it instantly switches to the active item picture then moves to the right.

Comment: @WajKhan I copied and pasted your code on the link above, the scenario you describe does not happens, when you click right, moves to the right from the current Active item, not for the item which originally  had the `active` class (in your code example: the first item)

Answer (score 0):

@MatiasFernandezMartinez

https://youtu.be/7Hr-EBEpVJ0 this is a video of the problem just to prove it is happening. As you can see the bottom three buttons work fine but the two left and right buttons bring up the problem I described

I'm assuming the problem is with my bootstrap or my jquery since the code does not bring you all problems

Comment: Should be, try to reproduce it on plunker or codepen, working backwards should help to find the issue, the html template is correct